# Calculate the average of specific vectors of various elements of a list() in R and convert to data.frame

Tags: r, list, vector, mean

I have a very large list() which has +2000 elements, where each element has two vectors (x and y) with different sizes between the elements of the list.

Example:

```
new_list<-list(data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),
                          y = c(3,4,5)),
               data.frame(x = c(3,2,2,2,3,8),
                          y = c(5,2,3,5,6,7)),
               data.frame(x = c(3,2,2,1,1),
                          y = c(5,2,3,3,2)))
```

I would like to average only the `x` vectors in this list to get something like this:

```
df_mean<-data.frame(x=c(2,3.333,1.8))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could calculate the `colMeans` per column that has x with `sapply` like this:

```r
data.frame(x = sapply(new_list, \(x) colMeans(x[grepl('x', names(x))])))
#>          x
#> 1 2.000000
#> 2 3.333333
#> 3 1.800000
```

---

@nicola suggested a better option like this (thanks!):

```r
data.frame(x = sapply(new_list, \(x) mean(x$x)))
#>          x
#> 1 2.000000
#> 2 3.333333
#> 3 1.800000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Why not just `\(x) mean(x$x)`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(new_list, ~ .x %>% 
    summarise(x = mean(x)))
         x
1 2.000000
2 3.333333
3 1.800000
```

Comment: one quest: in `map_dfr(new_list, ~ .x ` "x" is function or variable x from list?

Comment: @wesleysc352 it is a lambda function, `function(x) x` syntax in tidyverse. The `~` refers to `function(.x) `

Answer (score 2):

Good answer by Quinten.  I usually prefer to follow the KISS principle.  Here is a format that I find syntactically simpler:

```
len <- length(new_list)
sapply(1:len, function(z) mean(new_list[[z]][[1]]))
[1] 2.000000 3.333333 1.800000
```

Answer (score 2):

In this relatively simple case, I think I would prefer the more concise solution suggested by @quinten. However, if you need to calculate more statistics on the nested data frames, you could consider something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(data = new_list) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  summarise(
    x = mean(data$x)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>       x
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  2   
#> 2  3.33
#> 3  1.8
```

or alternatively

```r
tibble(data = new_list) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  summarise(
    data |> 
      summarise(x = mean(x))
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>       x
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  2   
#> 2  3.33
#> 3  1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also `enframe` the list and do a `mean` by group:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0 or higher
library(tibble)
enframe(new_list) %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  summarise(x = mean(x), .by = name)

#   name     x
#1     1  2   
#2     2  3.33
#3     3  1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`'s `rbindlist`:

```
data.table::rbindlist(new_list, idcol = TRUE)[, .(x = mean(x)), .id][, 2]
#>           x
#> 1: 2.000000
#> 2: 3.333333
#> 3: 1.800000
```